# How do I clone a player's in-game character into a gui?

Tags: lua, roblox

I want the player's in-game character, not their Roblox avatar picture, to be cloned and imported into a gui. The player inside the game has a modified StarterCharacter.

Essentially, I want each player to see their in-game character in a small gui.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can clone a player's character into a ViewportFrame, which will render 3d objects in a gui. You can read more about it here: https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/ViewportFrame